# Is it possible to use the OR condition in WP_Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Is it possible to use the OR condition in WP_Query to get the following sql output?

`where post_type = "post" or post_author = 123`

Comment: What are the input and output?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible to use the OR condition in WP_Query to retrieve posts based on multiple conditions. To achieve the desired SQL output where post_type is "post" or post_author is 123, you can use the meta_query parameter in WP_Query.

Here's an example of how you can construct the WP_Query arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'post_author',
            'value' => 123,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In this example, post_type is set to "post" and meta_query is used with the relation parameter set to 'OR'. Inside meta_query, an array is added with the key set to 'post_author', value set to 123, and compare set to '='.

This query will retrieve posts where either the post_type is "post" or the post_author is 123.

You can modify the meta_query array to include additional conditions or change the comparison operators as per your requirements.

Comment: Copy-paste from ChatGPT

Comment: No it's not a copy paste...in https://developer.wordpress.org/ side provide better guideline and all the developer follow this side not any AI Tool. i can create this code inspire by this code (https://prnt.sc/2dfmtXQhUywl)